# How to emulate sRGB on wider gamut or buy only sRGB monitor?

Tags: color-management, white-balance, display-calibration, srgb, wide-gamut

1. My Dell U2520D display shows magenta cast on a standard mode on both windows and mac. I think I am aware now that even if I use RGB ICC profile with this wider gamut display it will still look oversaturated by non color aware apps. And since my only need is sRGB space I tried the display's RGB mode but colors looked faded and not a good emulation of sRGB. I have a MacBook 16 2020 to reference for soft tuning of certain settings available in Nvidia panel like input range for 8bit RGB with a limited quantization range. That looks like a wild guess at targeting a restricted color space, colors looked off.
   So what else can be done to correct the colors if not accurate then at least remove the cast and keep them balanced without making them faded?
2. This monitor came with calibration report of deltaE < 1 so where and how does one use this accuracy? Is the ICC profile stored in display only? Then it should have worked with mac as mac shows one profile with dell's model name but results are oversaturated colors with standard mode, same results with sRGB or custom preset.
3. Are there sRGB only monitors for Windows' non color aware apps under 300$? I don't mind little popping colors as long as there is no cast to them and they look balanced. I read people loved older Ultrasharps like U2415h etc. (silly me who thought newer will be better). If Benq says PD2500Q is 100% sRGB & Rec 709 only, then can i assume i will not see oversaturated colors?
   And how do I use their factory calibration with window's non color aware apps? or Does it mean that this calibration is waste unless I use color aware apps? Also curious how hardware calibration devices fix desktop colors as its a non color aware program.

Comment: thanks no rush, i am not happy with my lack of experience in displays and trusting a brand blindly and paid 500$. Just want to understand things to make better purchase next time.

Comment: Zeus has beat me to a lot of the coverage on this - but just to note, **no** monitor ever arrives as flat & perfect as the manufacturers would have you believe. That's one reason why their supplied profiles are next to useless & you have to calibrate & profile using a colorimeter. I have two ostensibly identical Dell Ultrasharps & without profiles applied, one is red, the other green - which I see at every startup before the profiles switch in. As soon as they do, then they're identical.

Comment: well my doubts were mostly why Dell is not picking correct settings on mac, they say DCCI automatically adjusts profile user don't need to do anything, even when i tried multiple profiles on mac with every preset nothing gave me balanced colors. Out of the box i got very nice colors on my new Benq sRGB monitor with windows desktop.

Comment: I don't know what DCCI is, but unless you strap a colorimeter to the front of the display to calibrate it, all you've got is the manufacturer's 'average guess' as to how their screens look. Windows or Mac, neither of them can actually *see* what the screen is displaying.

Comment: I can't spend money on calorimeter which starts at 200$ here. Anyway my issues are resolved in Benq, can you please help me deciding if panel should be replaced? Even In my working light condition i see glow in corner and it's bugging me. [room_light](https://ibb.co/cCq9WYb) , [no_light](https://ibb.co/wQR63Jw)

Comment: You didn't mention that at all until 6 comments in. If it's not behaving as expected send it back. If you want two completely different screens to match, you're going to struggle without correct profiling.

Comment: Sry my bad then, i was also posting on dell support so might have missed few details. They basically refused saying nothing is wrong with panel, and what if second one also comes out like this. I saw in community someone gave a fix of creating DWM LUT for windows desktop which looks not so easy at the moment. Not so happy with Dell, gave it to someone else. The Benq looks good out of the box. Can you take a look at images i shared above if the Benq panel is fine or i should get it replaced, in normal lighting i see glare on left corner which is disturbing in dark scenes.

Comment: I'd have kept the Dell. That BenQ screen has a 'sunrise' effect I haven't seen so bad in 15 years & fortunately have never owned one. A black frame on a modern screen should be black. if it isn't, you bought the wrong screen.

Comment: Wanted to ask, which ultrasharp you have? Is it wide gamut? And if you use RGB ICC profile with windows does it change desktop colors as well? And how well your dell emulates RGB colors? I can live with screen bleed but not strong cast on colors for my use which is gaming, youtube etc. I have asked for a replacement for the Benq though due to the glow using your point, a black should look black.

Comment: I have 2 old ones - U2712H & U2713HM. The H is Adobe RGB, the HM is sRGB. Changing the profile changes everything, yes - that's the idea; but I don't know how well Windows handles this, I'm on Mac which has always been colour-managed throughout. I have no 'screen bleed' [I don't even know what that would be] nor any colour cast, because they are accurately profiled, with a good colorimeter, as is every screen in the building including the TVs. I can show any sRGB image on any screen & they all look the same.

Comment: Alright so you don't have to play with settings on a mac it appears. For windows would you know any preferred way of installing sRGB ICC for lets say your U2713HM without any calibration hardware. I am happy with only RGB monitor now but this has been my main doubt. And can you recommend color aware image and video apps for windows? thanks a lot for your answer, I really appreciate the explanations.

Comment: On any platform you can just use the manufacturer-supplied icc profile… with pretty random results, as already mentioned in my first comment above. That's why people use colorimeters. Without one, you just pick a profile that looks 'pretty', as you will never know if it is correct. I don't know enough about Windows to know which apps are correctly colour-managed.

Comment: @IndianUser1993 You spent $500 on the first monitor, then bought another monitor, yet you can't spend $200 on a colorimeter? It sounds more like you're not willing to spend what you need to get correct color. You'll almost always get more compliant color using a cheaper monitor that has been properly calibrated and profiled than you will using an expensive monitor that is not profiled regularly. (As monitors age they change over time, thus need to be readjusted every so often. I do mine every 2-4 weeks.)

Comment: @MichaelC Actually I sold my Dell monitor and got the Benq for cheaper price . I wanted something that can match MacBook and saw many happy reviews for Dell, since they are not on display I could only go by other's reviews. I still have some cash left for calibration device but since RGB space looks like it lacks contrast compared to what Mac shows I am okay with standard mode now which on Dell was way too oversaturated. So Dell might be premium and good with quality, its not for my use case. And I would like my games or Netflix to look better.

Comment: One last question, Will RGB space colors look same on a cheaper matte screen with 1000:1 contrast ratio vs something like 1600:1 glossy screen? In terms of pop and intensity of colors.

Comment: It appears you're still not grasping the idea that any profile you use is random unless the display is calibrated. If all you want is 'pretty' then pick whichever one you like best. You could also have done this with the Dell. Basically you blew money on not understanding how it works.

Comment: Didn't you say non color aware apps will not use an ICC profile? Getting the calorimeter was extra 200 on top of 500 and still I would not have got desired result in games and movies. No software or ICC file or guide to use their factory calibration along with wide native gamut of Ultrasharp was not good for my use. I no longer need accurate RGB colors as they are bit unsaturated so I like the standard mode on Benq to be good fit for my use as they are not too vibrant but good. And with money left I can buy a proper gaming panel for gaming.

Comment: I'm afraid there's nothing more I can say. You seem determined to make your own way in this, whilst ignoring advice & cherry-picking facts. I'm done. You do as you wish. Good luck.

Comment: Appreciate all the help by members, You are right I changed my choice from accurate RGB to near RGB to match visuals in terms of contrast to my Macbook. My monitor comes factory calibrated and RGB does look like it lacks contrast with other laptop displays I have with 1500:1 or even 1600:1 ratios. It could be due to cheaper panel but I like the standard mode and don't see use case for spending extra on calibration device.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try. First, some magenta cast is indeed "normal" when you use wide-gamut displays with non-colour-managed apps.

If your "need" is only sRGB (and Rec.709), then it would make sense to buy a "normal" (i.e. sRGB) monitor. This is particularly true if you edit video, because the output colour management for video is less common and more demanding. It does not *guarantee* that you get correct colours, but at least you'll get "normal" colours that most people get, without oversaturation, even if the app is not colour-aware or if you don't set up colour management. Still, it's better to get a decent monitor that explicitly declares sRGB compatibility (and not just "coverage"), like that Benq PD2500Q you mentioned.

That said, wide-gamut monitor is, by definition, more capable. But you will have to become "colour aware" yourself, and be very careful in selecting the apps you use and setting up the colour management (in the OS and in each app). Ideally, you should buy a colorimeter and profile your monitor. (This will certainly be cheaper than buying another monitor now).

Now, some technical details. If your monitor claims "deltaE < 1" everywhere (which I find a bit hard to believe), it must specify *with respect to what*. Presumably, the monitor must be in its "native" colour mode without any adjustments, and you must use an ICC profile they supply. This profile is *not* stored in the display; it should come as a file on a disc or download, and you must install it in your OS. Check the manual carefully. Then, and *only* if you use a colour-managed app, you should see correct colours without a cast or oversaturation. Note this does *not* normally apply to the desktop and GUI: they are usually not colour managed. If you are comparing with another monitor side by side, you should use a photo or a test chart open in a colour-managed app (on both sides).

Alternatively, if your monitor has a dedicated sRGB emulation mode (and you intend to trust it), you could use it. In this case, you need to tell the OS that you have such monitor by installing an sRGB profile in the OS; or, alternatively, you could remove any ICC profile and thereby cancel any colour management. (This latter is not that good because you'll see desaturated colours for images that *are* created with wider gamut, which is not that uncommon today).

If you don't like sRGB emulation now, it could be two things:

- You did install the full ICC profile and are applying it (i.e. viewing a photo in a colour-aware app). This would result in desaturated colours, because the OS believes the monitor is wide gamut whereas it is actually not (in the sRGB mode). Always remember that the ICC profile applies only to a specific mode; even if you change brightness, it may potentially shift colours. For this reasons good monitors lock most or all adjustments once they are calibrated.
- It is actually correct (more or less) but you don't like it. This psychological effect is rather common when you switch from bright saturated colours to limited colours. (Just like we perceive louder music "better"). But remember that colour management is about *correct* colours, not "nice" colours.

You can only be sure what is the case if you profile the monitor with a colorimeter and then don't change any of its settings. Note that monitors gradually change colours as they age, especially when new, so ideally you'd need to do it periodically.

Comment: Note that Mac is colour managed throughout, including all displays individually, the desktop & all apps [except a couple of browsers, Chrome & Firefox, which have *stupid* colour defaults. They can be overridden to correctly profile. See https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/124357/57929

Comment: Thanks, not sure where to get this RGB ICC profile, i left OS at default & monitor on RGB which looked undersaturated. Again all i want is normal RGB desktop colors on that UltraSharp monitor, which I still don't know how to get. I can't buy 200$ device as accuracy is not much of a concern, the color balance should be okay. And Dell manual says DCCI automatically handles the profiling part of display when we first connect it but clearly it failed to do so on mac and windows.

Comment: I got my Benq today, came with avg DeltaE of 0.51 , i have not applied the profile via their software yet and i already like this panel's color balance so don't even need that ICC  tuning. And I am bit surprised how screen can look more sharper than ultrasharp display. I have one concern though, there's visible glare on left corner which constantly bugs me. Shall i ask for a replacement as its common ISP panels has some glow in corners, a gray on left has shine to it while right corner has yellowish effect.